# Video capture only selected area via Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, screen-capture, getusermedia

I'm trying to write an Chrome Extension which allows user to select an area on screen and then captures video of that area only.
I read everything about `chrome.desktopCapture` API and about `getUserMedia()`, but I can't find an option for it, it seems like it allows only capturing of whole screen.
Is there any alternate way to do this via Chrome Extension?
Basically, input from user is coordinates of top left angle and the dimension of area will always be the same.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. As you've stated, `chrome.desktopCapture` can be used to capture content of screen, individual windows or tabs. You may check the [`chrome.tabCapture`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) to capture the visible area of the currently active tab.

Comment: @abielita hm I can't find that option for  chrome.tabCapture either